# Wedge product of tensors

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. If $(x^{i})$ are local coordinates on an open subset $U \subset M$, then for each $p \in U$, the coordinate basis $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}})_{p}$ gives rise to a dual basis $(dx^{i})_{p}$.

**My question:** Is this correct?
 $$T_{kl} dx^{k} \wedge dx^{l}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}) = \big(T_{kl}dx^{k} \otimes dx^{l}- T_{lk}dx^{l} \otimes dx^{k}\big)(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}) = 2 T_{kl}$$
where $T$ is the skew-symmetric tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$Assuming you're using the summation convention, your left-hand side isn't meaningful: $k$ and $l$ denote indices of summation in the tensor, but they're also used as indices on the coordinate vectors on which you're evaluating.

Writing $\dd_{k}$ for the $k$th coordinate vector, what you *do* have is
\begin{align*}
(T_{ij}\, dx^{i} \wedge dx^{j})(\dd_{k}, \dd_{\ell})
  &= T_{ij}\, (dx^{i} \otimes dx^{j} - dx^{j} \otimes dx^{i})(\dd_{k}, \dd_{\ell}) \\
  &= T_{ij}\, (\delta_{k}^{i} \delta_{\ell}^{j} - \delta_{k}^{j} \delta_{\ell}^{i}) \\
  &= T_{k\ell} - T_{\ell k},
\end{align*}
which is zero if $T$ is symmetric.

Comment: @user: As you've doubtless surmised, the result is indeed $2T_{k\ell}$ if $T$ is _skew_-symmetric. (Note, however, that your edited indices are no longer OK; as currently written, the right-hand side would be $2T_{ij}$, not $2T_{k\ell}$.)